# How to hide "Ran X test in Ys" with Python unittests

Tags: python, selenium

I am running a lot of selenium grid2 tests and am using unittests to assist me.

However, I would like to suppress the printing of

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

Does anyone know of a setting I can alter in order to fix this? It really bugs me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose what is outputted by a module by going into it's code and changing it.

In this case just search for what you don't want to be printed and remove the code that prints it.